# error when running a website in django server by cmd

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

when i want to see my django website in their server....i open cmd and go to manage.py directory:

```
 C:\Users\computer house\Desktop\ahmed>
```

and then i type :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but i see this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 317, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 106, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\computer house\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ahmed'
```

what can i do to solve this problem and run my website in the server correctly ?

Comment: Did you create an app named ahmed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i understood, You have started your project with the following command:

```
 C:\Users\computer house\Desktop> python startproject ahmed
```

After that I assume you have similar file structure:

```
ahmed/
├── ahmed/ # make sure this directory exists
│   ├── __init__.py # make sure this file exists.
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
```

Either the inner ahmed directory or `ahmed/__init__.py` does not exists. if `__init__.py` does not exist please create an empty file with taht name.

A python module is a file or directory. Every single file with `.py` extension is treated to be python modules by the interpreter. If you want a directory to be a python module you need to create `__init__.py` inside that directory. The file is run at import time of the module, if you do not know what you are doing leave `__init__.py` empty.

Answer (score 0):

check your current directory to have file names `__init__.py` also a directory named `ahmed` contains `__init__.py`